# How to reclassify building raster into 0 and 1

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm new to GIS and QGIS and I'm trying to follow this youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fitQGrrthH0

In the very beginning, the video discusses input data; there is a raster containing buildings that has been reclassified into 0 and 1 (1 for a building, 0 for not?). The video does not explain how to do this.

I have a shapefile of building footprints in London, how would I convert this first into a raster and then reclassify them accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

1. Create a raster layer with the same extent as your vector layer using the `Create Constant Raster Layer` tool. You can find this tool in the QGIS processing toolbox under Raster creation. Set the extent and resolution to match your vector layer.
   https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastercreation.html#create-constant-raster-layer
   [image]
   [image]
2. Clip your raster using your vector data (building footprints) with the `Clip Raster by Mask Layer` This tool is located also in the QGIS processing toolbox.
   This is the tool
   [image]
   The result will be a raster layer clipped to the extent of your vector layer.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rasterize (vector to raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#gdalrasterize) to convert the building polygons to a raster.

Set a `fixed value to burn = 1`, the output resolution, the output extent from the input polygon layer, assign a nodata value of 0 (or dont if you dont want to, you will still get the value 0), and output data type Byte:

[image]